# ¿Cómo retornar un método desde vuex sin que esté sea asincrono?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Me he dado cuenta de que los métodos en Vuex (desde mutations) siempre me retornan un [Object Promise], ¿No hay manera de usar métodos no asincronos en Vuex?

Tengo un método que se encarga de hacer un repaso a una lista de usuarios, encontrar al que tenga la ID proporcionada como parámetro

```
/*Este metodo esta en mutations (Vuex)*/
findUser(state, userId: number){
      let user: object = {}
        for(let actualUser of state.users){
          if (actualUser.id == userId){
            user = actualUser
          }
        }
      return user
}
```

A la hora de llamar a este método (que pasa por una acción), siempre recibo de vuelta un "[Object Promise]", ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Puedes publicar tu código? Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Las mutations son para modificar el state, no para retornar algo. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Si eso es cierto, significaría que para retornar datos del state debería usar actions, ¿Verdad?

Comment: Mmm... Para obtener datos del state puedes usar getters o directamente el state. No entiendo a que te refieres con retornar.

Comment: Pues, tengo un método en el que se itera una lista de usuarios, y se le pregunta a cada uno de ellos su ID a fin de encontrar un usuario en especifico.

Este método deposita al usuario que coincida con esa ID en una variable que eventualmente será retornada, pero siempre que intento usar esta función (desde Vuex) me retorna un [Object Promise].

Comment: Muestra el código. La lista de usuarios está en el state? El usuario que eventualmente encuentras en esa lista lo guardas en el state?

Comment: Listo amigo, acabo de editar el post.

Comment: Te diría que agregues al state una variable para guardar el usuario encontrado, por ejemplo `actualUser`. Entonces en la mutación, haces `state.actualUser = actualUser`. Luego en un componente obtienes el actualUser del state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no se cuanta experiencia tienes en Vue, pero justamente la separacion de la logica de Vuex es para evitar lo que te esta sucediendo.

Si vas a leer el estado debes usar getters. Luego en los componentes para simplificar la logica puedes usar mapGetters de vuex y los lees desde las propiedades computadas.

Las mutaciones hacen eso, mutar el state, de manera que no lo debes usar como lo estas usando, esta bien que la accion lo llame para alterar el state, pero repito, los valores del state los debes "mostrar" usando getters.

Lo ideal seria que en tu store tengas:

```
state: {
    users: [{...},{...}], // Aqui todos tus usuarios,
    user:null, // aqui el usuario seleccionado
},

getters: {
    user: state => state.user
},

mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
         state.user = payload // aqui solo se debe afectar a la variable del state.
    }
},

actions: {
    findUser({commit, state}, userId){
        user = state.users.filter(u => u.id == userId) // Asumimos que cada usuario es unico.

        if (user.length) {
            commit('setUser', user[0]) // si encuenta uno actualizamos la variable del estado.
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sea util.